# active record quering in rails 4 and postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have 2 models

```
Class Ride
  has_many :trips

  #state (string: active or expired)
end

Class Trip
  #date (Date attribute)
  scope :active, -> (start_at = Date.today) { where("trips.date >= ?", [Date.today, start_at].max) }  
end
```

Daily, I need update state on **Rides** *with active state* having **all** *trips with date attribute < Date.today*
how to perform this in 1 query?
i can archive such result using:

```
Ride.with_active_state.select{|r| r.trips.active.size ==0}
```

but it makes huje queries to count trips, eq:

```
    [1] pry(main)> Ride.with_active_state.select{|r| r.trips.active.size ==0}
   (7.3ms)  SELECT f_geometry_column,coord_dimension,srid,type FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name='rides'
  Ride Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "rides".* FROM "rides" WHERE (rides.workflow_state = 'active')
   (2.9ms)  SELECT f_geometry_column,coord_dimension,srid,type FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name='trips'
   (1.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trips" WHERE "trips"."ride_id" = $1 AND (trips.date >= '2013-09-24')  [["ride_id", 9]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trips" WHERE "trips"."ride_id" = $1 AND (trips.date >= '2013-09-24')  [["ride_id", 10]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trips" WHERE "trips"."ride_id" = $1 AND (trips.date >= '2013-09-24')  [["ride_id", 11]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trips" WHERE "trips"."ride_id" = $1 AND (trips.date >= '2013-09-24')  [["ride_id", 12]]
   (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trips" WHERE "trips"."ride_id" = $1 AND (trips.date >= '2013-09-24')  [["ride_id", 13]]
   (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trips" WHERE "trips"."ride_id" = $1 AND (trips.date >= '2013-09-24')  [["ride_id", 14]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trips" WHERE "trips"."ride_id" = $1 AND (trips.date >= '2013-09-24')  [["ride_id", 15]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trips" WHERE "trips"."ride_id" = $1 AND (trips.date >= '2013-09-24')  [["ride_id", 16]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trips" WHERE "trips"."ride_id" = $1 AND (trips.date >= '2013-09-24')  [["ride_id", 17]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trips" WHERE "trips"."ride_id" = $1 AND (trips.date >= '2013-09-24')  [["ride_id", 18]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trips" WHERE "trips"."ride_id" = $1 AND (trips.date >= '2013-09-24')  [["ride_id", 19]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trips" WHERE "trips"."ride_id" = $1 AND (trips.date >= '2013-09-24')  [["ride_id", 20]]
```

## ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add scopes on `Ride` with a `group` and `having` clause. It would check the count of all future trips of a ride and return the rides with 0 count.

```
Class Ride

  scope :active_state, where(state: "active")
  scope :with_nonactive_trips, -> (start_date = Date.today){ joins(:trips).
                                    group("rides.id").
                                    having( ["sum(trips.date > ?) = 0",start_date] ) }

end

Ride.active_state.with_nonactive_trips
# returns All the rides with state == active, alteast one trip and having no trips with date > Date.today
```

Using a `lambda` since you had it on the active scope in `Trip`. I am guessing you need to use a different date than `Date.today` for some queries.

Comment: ride can have 2 trips, one with expired date and another with date in future. in this case it shouldn't be selected in this query...

Comment: Some explanation as to why you need to use a lambda for the second scope might be a good idea.

Comment: and a ride always has at least 1 trip (expired or not but it exists always)

Comment: `scope :with_nonactive_trips, -> (start_date = Date.today){ includes(:trips).
      group("rides.id, trips.id").references(:trips).
      having( ["sum(cast(trips.date >= ? as int)) = 0",start_date] ) }` this did trick for me. thanks for helping!

Comment: @Danil be careful using `includes` as it creates an outer join table and would be a slow query if the table sizes are big . If `joins` does the job for you I would suggest using it over `includes`. You can use profiler to see the difference in query times.

Comment: with joins it selects wrong records. dunno why. if i change joins to includes it selects records i expect